# Mostrar resultados de tipo float cuando salen en entero

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
int NE, HT;
NE = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
HT = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
float S = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

float TS = HT * S;

Console.WriteLine("NUMBER = " + NE + "\r\n" + "SALARY = U$ " + TS);
```

El problema está en que si ponemos (**HT = 100**) y (**S= 5.5**) como respuesta dará = 550

Dependiendo del valor que se introduzca en (**S**) Ejemplo: Si se pone (**HT = 145**) y (**S = 15.55**) el 
resultado será (2254.75)

Necesito que quede de la siguiente forma = 550.00 o 2254.75 <-- Los dos últimos digitos pueden varoar

Comment: declara las variables como double.

Comment: Puedes formatear el número con los decimales que necesites, `$"{S:0.00}"`. En el ejemplo, `S` es tu variable, siguen los dos puntos (`:`) que indican el formato y `0.00` indica que van a haber dos decimales (`0.000` serían tres decimales, por ejemplo). [Aquí](https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) puedes ver una guía para los formatos.

Comment: @VRoxa Gracias amigo! justo lo que necesitaba. Funcionó perfectamente.